# Why appendChild replace parentElement?

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't this work:

```
 document.createElement('ul').appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
```

This happens also if I save created elements in vars and try to append one inside other (parent).

UPD: I need to return (node) or html like `<ul><li><li><ul>`

Comment: Please edit your to post in order to have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: because you did not add the ul to the body or any other div

Comment: If you just have that line in your code  then `document.createElement('ul')` creates a new DOM element. That element however is never added to the DOM tree as it is never assigned to any parent and will never appear anywhere.

Comment: I just need to create <ul><li></li><ul> elements, after I will append it to body object..so ho to do it?

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to append the `UL` to something...

```
const appendList = (trunk, n) => {
  const ul = document.createElement('ul')
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
  trunk.appendChild(ul)
}

appendList(document.body, 4)

const element = document.getElementById('element')
appendList(element, 2)
```

Alternatively, you could do something like the following

```
const appendList = (trunk, n) => {
  const ul = document.createElement('ul')
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
  document.querySelector(trunk).appendChild(ul)
}

appendList('#element', 10)
appendList('.otherElement', 3)
```

Comment: try it, and You will get just <li></li> appended to body(end of it)

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem is `document.createElement('ul')` is not yet added to document. So appending another element to it will not affect the document.

In the snippet below, I have appended the `ul` to `body` and then appended the `li` to the `ul`. Hope it helps.

```js
 document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(document.createElement('ul')).appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
```

Comment: But I don't want to append it to body object, I want to get just  <ul><li></li><ul> elements separate from body, is it possible?

Comment: Yup, but eventually you'd want to append them to some element, right? So then you could replace the `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]` part with something like `document.getElementsByID("#myelement")`.